# My submit button isn't sending anything to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I debug my program, the user that the action "Welcome" gets in the brackets, is all nulls. can someone please help me?

**This is the view**

```
@using LessIsMore.Models
@model User

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
}
<h2>Welcome</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Welcome","Welcome",FormMethod.Post)) { 

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtUserName">UserName: </label>
    <input type="text" id="txtUserName" class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtPassWord">PassWord: </label>
    <input type="password" id="txtPassWord" class="form-control" placeholder="PassWord" />
</div>     
  <button type="submit" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

}
```

**this is the controller**

```
namespace LessIsMore.Controllers
{
public class WelcomeController : Controller
 {
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Welcome()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Welcome(User u)
    {    
        //Some code here
        return View(u);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Your inputs do not have `name` attributes. I suggest you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics, inparticular how to generate view using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving a model to your view, but your aren't "using it". In other words, your input elements don't have a "name" attribute.

I suggest to use HtmlHelper methods, like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new {@class = "form-control"})
```

Or add the "name" attribute, matching the name of your model properties.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Andre's answer, just to give you a view of what putting the `name` attribute means..

If your `User` class has properties called `UserName` and `Password`.. then in your view you need to do this:

```
@using LessIsMore.Models
@model User

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
}
<h2>Welcome</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Welcome","Welcome",FormMethod.Post)) { 

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtUserName">UserName: </label>
    <input type="text" id="txtUserName" name="UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtPassWord">PassWord: </label>
    <input type="password" id="txtPassWord" name="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="PassWord" />
</div>     
  <button type="submit" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

}
```

So that when you hit submit, the right values are being passed through.

Let me know if this helps.